# How to write a function that takes 3 variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a function that takes a dataframe, team name, and whether the team is Home or Away. The return should be the the total number of points earned by this team for all home games or away games.

The df goes like this. it includes the dates, the teams, the home points, and away points

```
Date    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    HP  AP
0   09/08/2019  Liverpool   Norwich 3   0
1   10/08/2019  West Ham    Man City    0   3
2   10/08/2019  Bournemouth Sheffield United    1   1
3   10/08/2019  Burnley Southampton 3   0
4   10/08/2019  Crystal Palace  Everton 1   1
... ... ... ... ... ...
283 07/03/2020  Wolves  Brighton    1   1
284 07/03/2020  Burnley Tottenham   1   1
285 08/03/2020  Chelsea Everton 3   0
286 08/03/2020  Man United  Man City    3   0
287 09/03/2020  Leicester   Aston Villa 3
```

I have also list all the 20 teams in the premier leauge with

```
teams = df.HomeTeam.unique().tolist()
teams
['Liverpool',
 'West Ham',
 'Bournemouth',
 'Burnley',
 'Crystal Palace',
 'Watford',
 'Tottenham',
 'Leicester',
 'Newcastle',
 'Man United',
 'Arsenal',
 'Aston Villa',
 'Brighton',
 'Everton',
 'Norwich',
 'Southampton',
 'Man City',
 'Sheffield United',
 'Chelsea',
 'Wolves']
```

I tried doing this

```
def Teampoints (PL_df, teams, HP, AP):
    return (PL_df.HP, PL_df.AP)
```

but when I did

```
Teampoints(df,'Liverpool','home')
```

it gives me an error. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `def Teampoints (PL_df,teams,HP,AP)` creates a function with 4 arguments, yet `Teampoints(df,'Liverpool','home')` calls it with 3.

Comment: Im sorry bout that, im pretty new to functions. what should i do about it?

Comment: Either create the function with 3 arguments or call it with 4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your function should be like this:

```
def Teampoints(PL_df,team,home_or_away):
   if home_or_away == 'Home':
      return PL_df[PL_df['HomeTeam']==team].HP
   elif home_or_away == 'Away':
      return PL_df[PL_df['AwayTeam']==team].AP
```

Now you should be able to call `Teampoints(df,'Liverpool','Home')`!

Comment: This is the answer i have been looking for! Thank you so much brother!

Answer (score 0):

Function definition of Teampoints:

```
def Teampoints (PL_df, teams, HP, AP):
    return (PL_df.HP, PL_df.AP)
```

The function defined expects 4 parameters : df, teams, HP and AP.

So, calling the function with 4 arguments would solve the error. For example,

```
AP = #your choice of input
Teampoints(df,'Liverpool','home',AP)
```